# Formatting text into columns

Tags: shell, columns, text-formatting

I have a file with two columns as shown below(example):

FILE 1:

```
John 1
Peter 2
Michael Rod 3
Su 7
Louise 9
```

I need to format this and my expected output should be:

FILE 1:

```
John        1
Peter       2
Michael Rod 3
Su          7
Louise      9
```

Comment: where are the 2 columns?

Comment: Both outputs seems to be the same. Could you please give more details on your question?

Comment: How are columns defined? Is there a tab or some other character between the name and the number? How can we know that `Michael Rod 3` is 2 columns and not 3?

Comment: ditto what mmmint and terdon said; can you specify, for example, that it's the *last* column that needs to be indented over to allow for the width of the longest line?

Answer (score 24):

If the input had been only two columns, I would have suggested to use `column -t`.  This doesn't quite work here though since the `column` utility will treat any number of spaces or tabs as column delimiters:

```
$ column -t file1
John     1      
Peter    2      
Michael  Rod  3 
Su       7      
Louise   9
```

"Michael Rod" is two columns, so that single row has one column more than the other rows, which messes up the output.

We can work around this by inserting a tab character before the last column and then let `column` use (only) that as a delimiter:

```
$ awk '{ $NF = "\t" $NF; print }' file1 | column -t -s $'\t'
John          1
Peter         2
Michael Rod   3
Su            7
Louise        9
```

In Awk, `NF` is the number of fields (columns), and `$NF` is the data in the last field.  The script I'm using simply *modifies* the data of the last field by prepending a tab character, before printing the complete line.

If your shell doesn't understand `$'\t'`, then you could pick another character that is not part of the data:

```
awk '{ $NF = "@" $NF; print }' file1 | column -t -s '@'
John          1
Peter         2
Michael Rod   3
Su            7
Louise        9
```